How to setup a lab for Kerberos Unconstrained Delegation in Active Directory?
I'm setting up a lab environment for unconstrained delegation in Active Directory. I've encountered some issues and would appreciate guidance on the correct configuration. Here's my current setup:
Lab Environment:

Domain Controller (DC01): Running Windows Server, hosting the domain "contoso.local"
Web Server (IIS01): Windows Server joined to the domain

Configuration Steps:
Domain Controller (DC01) Setup:
Created and configured as always
Web Server (IIS01) Configuration:
Joined to the "contoso.local" domain
In Active Directory Users and Computers on DC01:

Modified IIS01 computer object setting delegation to "Trust this computer for delegation to any service (Kerberos only)"


Installed "Web Server (IIS) role (Also including "Windows Authentication" role)
Service Account Setup:
Created a new user "web01svc" in Active Directory
Set SPNs for the account:

HTTP/web01
HTTP/web01.contoso.local

In user ("web01svc") properties, set delegation to "Trust this user for delegation to any service (Kerberos only)"

IIS Configuration on IIS01:
Created a new application pool "web01" with identity set to "web01svc"

Created a new website "web01" and configured authentication settings like this:


Here I found the following warning: "Kernel mode authentication cannot be used with Negotiate providers." (Is this significant?)

Finally, the web.config file generated is:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <identity impersonate="true" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>

Problems
When I go to DC01 I am unable to connect to "http://web01.contoso.local", but can connect to "http://iis01.contoso.local"
When attempting to access the site from DC01, I receive a "500 Internal Server Error". In IIS01 this error is the same but the browser shows: "Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions"

What steps am I missing or configuring incorrectly?
I would greatly appreciate any guidance, explanations, or links to relevant resources that could help me understand and correctly implement this lab scenario.
I've also created a diagram illustrating the global desired setup:

Thank you and I hope I have explained myself well (or at least understandable).

Try testing from a host that isn't the DC.

I'll try it... About the configuration process. Did you see something wrong? Thanks!

You may want to rephrase the question as a how to create an IIS web site. Permissions for the configuration file is fairly basic.

Specifically: you're using a web.config file in a different user's desktop -- likely true that the service account can't read it.  I'd put the website and its config somewhere else, like a dedicated path for websites.  in an OOB environment, I would be thinking C:\inetpub\wwwroot.

curious why you've got unconstrained configured on the computer and the service accounts?  Seems like the service account would be sufficient...
